# Check if 3 string inputs are in alphabetical order

Tags: python

I need to ask for 3 names and compare them after to see if they have been given in alphabetical order or not.

I tried things like if (name_1 < name 2) and (name_2 < name_3) but python cannot compare strings like that. It's a first prog course so we cannot use a list since it has not been teached yet.

```
...Three inputs to ask for 3 names here...

if (name_1 < name_2) and (name_2 < name_3):
    print("The names are in alphabetical order.")
elif (name_1 > name_2) and (name_2 > name_3):
    print("The names are not in alphabetical order.")
```

I get no errors but also no results.

Comment: Python can, and does, compare strings like that.  Your code does not print output in all cases, only those in which the three strings are in alphabetical or reverse alphabetical order.  Please clarify your problem.

Comment: Hello @Prune thank you for your answer! If I add an else it will print what's in else but even when I give names in alphabetical order like Alexander, Bernard, Caroline it goes in the else while it should go in the first if statement.

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: @Prune you found the issue; it's that he doesn't have an `else` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python can compare strings with `<` and `>`: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types

The problem is you are only printing for the cases of:

- strings are in alphabetical order
- strings are in reverse alphabetical order

Instead, try this:

```
if name_1 < name_2 and name_2 < name_3:
    print("The names are in alphabetical order.")
else:
    print("The names are not in alphabetical order.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare multiple things at the same time by chaining them.  This also avoids your incomplete implementation of `else` (your elif doesn't match all non-alphabetical cases).

```
name_1, name_2, name_3 = 'a', 'b', 'c'

alphabetical = name_1 < name_2 < name_3
a_str = '' alphabetical else ' not'
print('The names are%s in alphabetical order' % a_str)
```

This prints `The names are in alphabetical order`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use lists, add the names in a list and compare.

```
n = ['paul', 'mike', 'julie']
z = n.copy()
n.sort()
# compare the lists
n == z
# you should have False
```

Comment: The question says lists are not allowed

Comment: my bad @wcarhart

Answer (score 0):

In Python, comparisons can be chained, so there should be no need to use `and`.

Use an `else` statement, instead of an `elif` statement for when they aren't in alphabetical order.

```
>>> name_1 = "Aaron"
>>> name_2 = "Alice"
>>> name_3 = "Bob"
>>> if name_1 < name_2 < name_3:
    print("The names are in alphabetical order.")
else:
    print("The names are not in alphabetical order.")


The names are in alphabetical order.
```

Also note that capitalization matters:

`"aaron" > "Alice"` is True, and `"aaron" > "Aaron"` is also True.

To get around this, make everything lower case for the comparisons:

```
>>> name_1 = "aaron"
>>> if name_1 < name_2 < name_3:
    print("The names are in alphabetical order.")
else:
    print("The names are not in alphabetical order.")


The names are not in alphabetical order.
>>> if name_1.lower() < name_2.lower() < name_3.lower():
    print("The names are in alphabetical order.")
else:
    print("The names are not in alphabetical order.")


The names are in alphabetical order.
```